# Имя таблицы через переменную в запросе Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Есть множество однотипных таблиц, различных только по именам и данным. Количество столбцов и их названия идентичны. Вопрос - как в C# построить запрос к mysql что бы вместо имени конкретной таблицы была переменная? В MS SQL эту задачу я решал так :

```
 string TableName = "table 1";
 $@"UPDATE {TableName} SET [ColumnName] = @name1 where (ID_customers = @id)"
```

Видел пример подобного запроса на php а как построить запрос к Mysql на C#?

Comment: а с интерполяцией строк для MySql не получается?

Comment: @MikhailM интерполяция это то, пример чего я привел ?

Comment: да, вы же по сути просто составляете строку запроса, который будет отправлен БД. MySql в этом отношении не должен ничем отличаться от MS SQL

Comment: вы правы. нужно было просто [ поменять на `

Comment: $@"UPDATE {TableName} SET `ColumnName` = @name1 where (ID_customers = @id)"